# evaluate variable in Unix at runtime

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have somewhat wierd requirement to be resolved in Unix script.

supose i have a file containing

```
a=4
b=3
c=a+b
d=c+a
e=a+b+5+d
```

I have to get output like

```
a=4
b=3
c=7
d=11
e=23
```

I have tried using AWK using the logic that whatever in RHS variable avaiable I will replace it with ${variable}
for example

```
e=a+b+5+d
```

will comeout as

```
e=${a}+${b}+5+${d}
```

But I am not sure how to get value of `"a,b,d"` in the currently running shell in AWk. Used "source" keyword after writing the a=4 thing to file. but it is not working.

Please suggest some other way because I don't think my way is going to work.

Comment: Is addition the only operator you need to worry about?  Also, will any variable ever be reassigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the formulas in a file `expr.sh`, then this will work:

```
sed -e 's:=:=$((:' -e 's:$:)):' expr.sh |bash -x
```

Explanation: `e=$((a+b+5+d))` will evaluate the expression between `$((` and `))` (including expanding all variables) and assign the result to `e`

Answer (score 1):

```
bc -q inputfile <(echo '"a="; a; "b="; b; "c="; c; "d="; d; "e="; e; halt')
```

If your shell or environment doesn't support process substitution:

```
{ cat inputfile; echo '"a="; a; "b="; b; "c="; c; "d="; d; "e="; e; halt'; } | bc -q
```

If you're using GNU `bc`, you can use a `print` statement:

```
bc -q inputfile <(echo 'print "a=", a, "\n", "b=", b, "\n", "c=", c, "\n", "d=", d, "\n", "e=", e, "\n"; halt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the shell itself, no need for external tools.

If the shell is ksh, bash or zsh, declare the variables as integers and each assignment will perform the arithmetic operation as it is parsed.

```
typeset -i a b c d e
. ./assignments.sh
```

If you don't know the list of variables in advance, parse it out.

```
typeset -i $(<assignments.sh sed -n 's/^ *\([A-Z_a-z][0-9A-Z_a-z]*\)=.*/\1/p')
. ./assignments.sh
```

Note that this assumes that there is no whitespace inside the arithmetic computations or around the `=` signs, and there is nothing else in the file (it's ok to have comments in shell syntax, e.g. lines beginning with `#`).

If you can only assume a POSIX shell, or if the arithmetic assignments contain spaces, you'll need to do the arithmetic computations explicitly.

```
while IFS='=' read -r var expr; do
  var=$((set -f; echo $var)) # strip leading and trailing whitespace from $var
  eval "$var=\$(($expr))"
done <assignments.sh
```

Again, this code assumes that the file only contains lines like

```
a=3
b = a + 7
```

Add error checking if you need it.